# Question about limits $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-2}{e^{1/x}\cdot x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How to calculate this:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-2}{e^{1/x}\cdot x}$$

Comment: HINT: Multiply the numerator and denominator by $\dfrac1x$.

Comment: Which formula for e Should I use in order to remove e

Comment: There’s no reason to remove $e$: $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{1/x}$ can be calculated directly.

Comment: if I replace x with 1/x I get 1 for answer is this correct?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘replace $x$ with $1/x$’? If you literally do exactly that, you convert the problem into $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1/x-2}{e^x/x}\;;$$ is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Comment: Yes, that also works, and yes, the limit is $1$.

Comment: I think that the OP has shown some effort in the comments, so the question need not be closed for this reasons. (If you think that it helps with adding context to the post, some of the OP's comments can be summarized in the formulation question.)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $\dfrac{x-2}{x} \to 1$ and $e^{1/x} \to 1$. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can write the limit as
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-1/x}\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-\frac{2}{x}}{1} \\
=\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-1/x}\cdot 1 \\
=1.
\end{equation*}
Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-2}{e^{1/2}\cdot x}=1.
\end{equation*}
Note that we can also use L'Hopital's rule. Set 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=\frac{x-2}{e^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot x}.
\end{equation*}
Taking the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ give us $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. Differentiating and using the product rule gives
\begin{equation*}
f'(x)=\frac{1}{-\frac{1}{x}e^{\frac{1}{x}}+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}=\frac{1}{-0e^0+1}=1
\end{equation*} 
as $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying both the numerator and the denominator by $1/x$ yields $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1- 2/x}{e^{1/x}} = \frac{\lim_{x\to \infty} 1-2/x}{\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{1/x}} = \frac{1}{1} = 1$$